# Terraria Tablet Controls on a PC

Tags: terraria, mods, terraria-mobile

Is it possible to add Terraria-Mobile-style controls into Terraria PC, using mods, a third-party program over Terraria or otherwise?

I'm asking this since someone I play Terraria with has a Windows 10 touch-screen, and they would like a more Mobile-like experience (where they can still defeat the Moon Lord).